# ActionController::Live - SSE in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multithreading, concurrency, server-sent-events, puma

I want changes in the database to be reflected on the page without server reload.

**controller**

```
class ProductController < ApplicationController
  include ActionController::Live

  def index
    @product = Product.available
    response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/event-stream'
    sse = SSE.new(response.stream)
    sse.write @product
  ensure
    sse.close
  end
end
```

**view**

```
<p><%= @product[:price] %></p>
```

I am using Puma.

When I update the product in the database, the changes are not reflected on the webpage.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

Rails cannot update the view in real time.  It serves the html and then it's up to some JavaScript to listen to the stream and handle the events.

I've created a gem, Shower, that handles all of this for you.  https://github.com/kpheasey/shower

Using Shower, the solution would be something like this.

First you need to publish the update event,  this can be done with an after_update callback on the Product model.

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    after_update :publish_event

    def publish_event
        Shower::Stream.publish('product.update', self)
    end
end
```

Then you need some javascript to listen to the event stream and act on it.

```
$ ->
    stream = new Shower('/stream', ['product.update'])

    stream.addEventListener('product.update', (event) ->
      product = JSON.parse(event.data)
      $('p').html(product.price)
    )
```

Comment: Redis is currently not in my stack. Is there any special configuration I must put into to place for this to work? @KPheasey

Comment: You just need to install redis on your local system.  It's pretty easy to install via Homebrew on a mac, or through the package on linux systems, https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-redis

Comment: it seems like Shower creates a route ---get '/stream', to: 'shower/stream#index'--- Is the stream streamed to /stream? If so, upon visiting the page, Rails complains: "Can't modify frozen hash" @KPheasey